# HTML5 <div> centered inside <body>

Tags: html

Is there a way to place a div inside body, centered, with given left-right margins equal to x and top-bottom margins, equal to y? Nothing except of the div (and its children) is presented in the document.

UPDATE. I want the following:

[image]

Also, I'd be glad to have a more common solution for the case, when x1 != x2, y1 != y2 (though a solution for my particular case x1==x2, y1==y2 is appreciated).

Comment: If margin-left and margin-right for the div element are equal, the div gets centered horizontally. Isn't it? Or have I misunderstood your question? (However, where the div element is positioned vertically depends on margin-top.)

Comment: Yes, it is centered horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fixed positioning.  It won’t work in IE6, though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='de' lang='de'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            #bla {
                position: fixed;
                top: 30px;
                left: 60px;
                right: 60px;
                bottom: 30px;
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='blah'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See it in action: http://obda.net/stackoverflow/position-fixed.html

Answer (score 8):

Better solution(?):
Set margin-left and margin-right for the div to "auto"

Comment: What are the browsers that support this?

Answer (score 4):

The best I can do without CSS3 is to use two divs.

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
div.child {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/CatChen/VGpdv/4/

**Update:** If CSS3 implementation is acceptable, it's a lot easier:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center

Comment: Then it's a lot easier! See this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center

Comment: This gives me browser scrollbars, due to the parent div positioning. Anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use javascript if you want the margins to be the same in all browzers.

```
<body>
  <div id="the_div" style="margin: 20 auto;margin-bottom:0;width:300px;">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dim = (function () {
      var _pW, _pH;
      if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
        _pW = document.body.offsetWidth;
        _pH = document.body.offsetHeight;
      }
      if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && 
          document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth) {
        _pW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
        _pH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
      }
      if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
        _pW = window.innerWidth;
        _pH = window.innerHeight;
      }

      return { width : _pW, height : _pH };
    })();

    var div = document.getElementById( "the_div" );
    div.style.height = dim.height - 20 + "px";
  </script>
<body>
```

Comment: Also if you want to support old IE versions, give the following additional styles: `body { text-align: center; } .container { text-align: left; }` (requires you give your "main" div the class "container")

Comment: Why would _want_ to do that? Have to, maybe, but _want_ to?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in FireFox 5. Div's height is just enough to contain a content (a line of text), not is body height minus y * 2. Full html: <html style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<head>
<style>
div
{
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="width:100%;height:100%; background-color:red;">
<div style="margin: 20px auto;padding: 0 30px;">
Just content.
</div>
<body>

</html>

Comment: Your question was poorly defined, also that javascript block probably will have to get called on window resize

Comment: 2Mimisbrunnr. The page is just designed this way. By a designer. This is a fullscreen web-app for different tablets with different screens. Nevertheless, all margins should be the same in pixels everywhere. The question of good this design or not is offtopic for me.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry for not being accurate with my question. I know, how to do this with a script and absolute positioning. I'm wondering is it possible without them. Sorry one more time.

Comment: well then, nope. Not to have it work across all browzers and sizes